# Windows server 2012 "Invalid algorithm specified."

Tags: c#, encryption, windows-server-2012-r2

When I try to sign data it always says Invalid algorithm specified. I am using following code:

[image]

Here is my Certificate Details.

[image]

Please Help me, Thanks.

Comment: Screenshots are appropriate for things like CertUI.  But not for code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of

```
RSACryptoServiceProvider csp = (RSACryptoServiceProvider)cert.PrivateKey;
return csp.SignHash(hash, CryptoConfig.MapNameToOid("SHA256"));
```

use

```
using (RSA privateKey = cert.GetRSAPrivateKey())
{
    return privateKey.SignHash(hash, HashAlgorithmName.SHA256, RSASignaturePadding.Pkcs1);
}
```

(Requires .NET 4.6+)

The problem is your `RSACryptoServiceProvider` object is using the CAPI `PROV_RSA_FULL` provider, which predates SHA-2.  SHA-2 signatures (from the software provider) require the key be in `PROV_RSA_AES`, a fact mostly controlled by the key creation / PFX import.

There's a workaround you can do for rebinding the provider type to still use the [soft-deprecated `RSACryptoServiceProvider`](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/wiki/ApiCompat#systemsecuritycryptographyrsacryptoserviceprovider), but particularly in code like this (where the object does not leave the method) you should switch to using `cert.GetRSAPrivateKey()` and avoid casting the returned `RSA` object beyond the algorithm base class.